Persist child and parent entity from OneToOne relationship with cascade in Spring JPA
I have two entities in my Spring API with a OneToOne relationship: Customer and CustomerAddress (this is just a simplified example of the problem). Each of these entities have their own tables. Here is the simplified definition of the tables and the entities:
customer (
    id uuid,
    name string
)

customer_address (
    customer_id uuid, // This is a FK that references customer
    street string
)

@Entity
class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    CustomerAddress customerAddress;

}

class CustomerAddress {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    UUID id; // This should be the same id as the parent

    @Column(name = "street")
    String street;
}

I want to create a Customer with it's related CustomerAddress and be able to persist CustomerAddress as cascade when I call .save() on the customer. I already tried different approaches but I got different errors, such as:
Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

insert or update on table "..." violates foreign key constraint

How can I correctly set the association between these two entities in order to be able to correctly persist both of them in one save?

Following this tutorial from Thorben Janssen I was able to successfully save both entities in a OneToOne relation with one save. The final entities looked like this:
@Entity
class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    CustomerAddress customerAddress;

}

class CustomerAddress {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    UUID id;

    @Column(name = "street")
    String street;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @OneToOne
    Customer customer;
}

And this is the code that I used to persist the customer:
var customer = new Customer("joe")
var customerAddress = new CustomerAddress("street 1")

customer.setCustomerAddress(customerAddress)
customerAddress.setCustomer(customer)

customerRepository.save(customer)

